# How to populate given SQL records to all UserID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in this form:

```
id | firstname | lastname | userid
---+-----------+------------------------
1  | john      | smith    | 545868-5434-343435-35353
2  | adam      | finger   | 545868-5434-343435-35353
3  | teri      | marti    | 545868-5434-343435-35353
4  | pei       | port     | 545868-5434-343435-35353
```

In the DB i have many `userid`  i need to populate the very same `firstname` and `lastname`  to all `userid` found in the `Database`

Here is my SQl Query

```
SELECT  

cID, c.firstname,c.lastname,

[s].UserID,c.OwnerID

FROM  
Customer INNER JOIN [s] ON c.OwnerID = [s].UserID AND c.AssignedtoID =
[s].UserID AND c.CreatedByUserID = [s].UserID
```

*AssignedtoID is the same as UserID*

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Why do u have same `user_id` for all users ?

Comment: oups,  i dont have the same id for all users.. i want to populate current records to all users in the database

Comment: @D-Shih I would like to populate the 4 customer records to all users ( apologies i did not include the other user ids in the examples)

Comment: Your question is still unclear, add some sample data from both tables

Comment: You want to Update the table , so that for same userid, fname, and lname should be same. is my understanding correct.?

Comment: @B House i'm adding some data as per your request, thanks!

Comment: @Sahi yes update for (ALL) * userID  === same  firstname and lastname

Answer (score 0):

is this helpful for you.?

```
    Create table #tmpCustomer (id int, firstname VARCHAR(50),lastname VARCHAR(50),userid VARCHAR(100))


    INSERT INTO #tmpCustomer 
    SELECT 1, 'john','smith','545868-5434-343435-35353'
    union
    SELECT 2,'adam','finger','545868-5434-343435-35353'
    union
    SELECT 3,'teri','marti','545868-5434-343435-35353'
    union
    SELECT 4, 'pei','port','545868-5434-343435-35353'
    union
    SELECT 5, 'abc','xyz','545868-5434-343435-35354'
    union
    SELECT 6, 'mno','ert','545868-5434-343435-35354'


    --select * from #tmpCustomer

    ;with cte1 AS(Select row_number()over(partition by userid order by id) rn,* from #tmpCustomer ),
          cte2 AS (select * from cte1 where rn=1 ) 

    update t
    set t.firstname=c.firstname
    from #tmpCustomer t
    JOIN cte2 c on t.userid=c.userid 

    select * from #tmpCustomer

    drop table #tmpCustomer
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if i good understand your question, try solution posted below

DECLARE @cust as table (firstname varchar(20),lastname Varchar(20))

Insert @cust 
values
('Suzan','Smith')

declare @id as table (id int identity,anything varchar(20),row_inserted datetime2 default (cast(sysdatetime() as datetime2)))

INSERT @id
(anything,row_inserted)

SELECT 'x' ,'20180305'
union all
select 'y','20180305'
union all
select 'z','20180305'

select s.id,c.firstname,
c.lastname
from @id as s
cross join @cust as c